# Errno::ECONNREFUSED in Users::RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, devise

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def destroy
    super
  end
end
```

どうして接続できないのかがわかりません。

#### データベースが原因の場合

どこを見れば良いのかおしえてください。(sqlite3)

#### devise が原因の場合

参考になるドキュメントまたは回答をいただければ幸いです。

#### 情報が足りない場合

催促していただければ幸いです。

#### 追加の情報

log そのまま

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `initialize'
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `open'
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `tcp_socket'
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `block in do_start'
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:82:in `block in timeout'
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:70:in `catch'
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:70:in `timeout'
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:549:in `do_start'
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:519:in `start'
  mail (2.6.3) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
  mail (2.6.3) lib/mail/message.rb:2141:in `do_delivery'
  mail (2.6.3) lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `block in deliver'
  actionmailer (4.1.6) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:527:in `block in deliver_mail'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionmailer (4.1.6) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:525:in `deliver_mail'
  mail (2.6.3) lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `deliver'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:173:in `send_devise_notification'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:102:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:158:in `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:483:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in `save'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
  devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:15:in `create'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (21.4ms)
```

Comment: 情報が不足しているので`log/development.log`やエラー画面からエラー発生時のスタックトレースを貼り付けてください。

Comment: コードやスタックトレースを載せるときはスペース4文字でインデントしてください。そうするとコードブロックとして表示されます。範囲指定してからテキストエリア上部の「{ }」をクリックするのもOKです。詳しくはこちらのページを参照してください。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

スタックトレースを見ると

```
  /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `initialize'
```

でエラーが起きているので、メールの送信に失敗しているようです。

この問題が起きているのは開発環境ですか？それとも本番環境（ネット上のwebサーバー）でしょうか？（実際に送信しようとしているのでおそらく後者のような気がします）

いずれにせよ、データベースの問題ではなくメール送信の設定に問題があるので、こちらのドキュメント等を参照して適切なメール設定を行ってください。

http://railsguides.jp/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer%E3%82%92%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございました。
おっしゃいます通りaction_mailer の設定がおかしかったことに加えて

`
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
`
この３行が必要でありました。
environment.rb です。